# Force HDFS to write blocks to specific host

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to force HDFS to write all blocks of a file to specific host. Is this possible and if it is what is the easiest way to achieve it?

Why? I am writing a new instance allocation algorithm for a cluster computing framework based on hdfs. Having all blocks of a file on one host makes comparing the new allocation system (which takes data locality into account) to the old one much easier, especially on a smaller cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't do this - what happens if that host goes down?

If you look at a particular file in HDFS (that has a number of blocks), you'll often see that a number of the blocks are indeed hosted by the same data node, but there is no guarantee of this.